# Windows RT/8 Tablet - Deploy from Windows 7

Tags: cordova, deployment, windows-7, windows-8, tablet

I have been looking around forever, MSDN is not very clear at all (or perhaps I've been doing this all day)

Here is my situation. I am building a PhoneGap/Cordova app and was recently asked to port it over (by Microsoft themselves) to the Windows Phone Platform, so work went ahead and bought me a Windows8 Tablet/RT.

I am currently running Windows7, and I read an article that you can Deploy Windows7 Phone Apps to the Windows8 Tablet (Xap packaging or whatever)

But I can not get the Windows8 tablet to be recognized by my PC, I'm not even sure how to begin with this step.

Am I running the wrong equipment? The app I am developing is ment for the mobile-framework, however this new brand of Microsoft is very confusing and starting to get under my skin. Am I under the right assumption that I can deploy a WindowsPhone7 app and deploy to the Windows8 tablet? I can get it fine in VS2010 but I just can not do the deploy step.

Nothing is straight forward and I can not find any articles as the search terms are confused (Im typing deploying to windows 8 tablet from windows 7)

I have Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. I've managed to install the Windows8 Phone SDK using the /layout command (And I have windows7.1 Phone SDK)

I know nothing of the Microsoft Equipment as I've been avoiding it until recently ha! Most of my dev. has been done via Mac computer

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you very much

Comment: i've bit the bullet revived an old laptop and going to download windows8. I hope this works.

Comment: you can't deploy Windows Phone 7 apps to Windows 8 - you could deploy the XAP to Windows 8 emulator, but that's not going to run on Windows RT (Surface and other ARM devices). You said you installed the Windows 8 Phone SDK, where did you install that? It requires Windows 8 or Windows 8 Pro (not Windows RT).

Comment: I did /layout on the windows 8 phone sdk and it installed, but looks like it merely extracted. I have no idea whats going on anymore haha, I'll just convert an older PC, I just didn't want to upgrade to windows8 on my personal machine as I'm using it to develop other programs so I'd rather not run the risk. Thanks for the explanation, my mind is foggy Ive been at it all day (and its 43 degree heat here in Australia!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bit the bullet and installed windows8. Not a big fan of it... but such is life